# Apache Hive implementation in windows

Tags: hive

I try to start the hive in my windows machine , I successfully the started, created the database and tables , but unable to put the select query from hive. While putting select query we are facing the below issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxYnw.png)

I check the classpath , that's having latest guava-19 jar

Anyone faced same issue and resolved ?

Comment: Guava 19 is not the latest, by the way, but your issue is that you cannot use Java higher than 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue was with guava jar, having a different a version guava jar in hadoop library and in hive library , I replaced the guava jar with guava-19 in hadoop library , now both libries have same guava version jar , so issue is reloved

Answer (score 0):

You must have matched versions of libraries, use Maven or similar to get the right version of jars, that exception is complaining about different jvm classfile versions.

As you've not specified which Spark version you are using it'd be difficult to guess, but I'd suggest no higher than 15.0 as that is compatible with most versions of Spark and Databricks.  Again prefer to take the version from either Maven or use the distribution version directly.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but issue is not with jvm, also I didn't use spark execution engine, i used tez